# How to delete all nagios availability history data?

Tags: nagios

After play a little with nagios tuning some variables etc. I want go to production and clear all the so far collected availability data, so my nagios history begin today. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Nagios Support Forum here: [Clear state, logs, etc. What is the best way?](http://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10430&p=53110)

Shut down the nagios service and remove the retention file:

```
service nagios stop
rm /usr/local/nagios/var/retention.dat
service nagios start
```

Delete the archived nagios.log files:
`/usr/local/nagios/var/archives/`

That said, I've never actually done either of these in any Nagios environment...so make sure you backup the folders/files first somewhere and then try it and verify it did what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

> It could be that when the service was removed, it did not get removed
> from the retention.dat file or the objects.cache file.
>
> ```
> /usr/local/nagios/var/retention.dat
> /usr/local/nagios/var/objects.cache
> ```
>
> When nagios starts, it reads those files for the running
> configurations and for the status when the system was shutdown.   What
> you could do is to stop the Nagios daemon, edit those files and remove
> the entry and start the Nagios Daemon when you are done.

[Reference](https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=43668)

In my case I've just moved those files into other place (home folder, for example):

```
$ sudo systemctl stop nagios
$ sudo mv /usr/local/nagios/var/retention.dat ~/
$ sudo mv /usr/local/nagios/var/objects.cache ~/
$ sudo systemctl start nagios
```

And it looked like I've started nagios the first time.